# Security Issues: Injecting web3js into the window object of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular, web3js

So I recently started learning web3js (using it with angular). And since using web3js with angular through the npm package is a bit cumbersome I was instead using a web3js cdn and injected it into the window object of my HTML (at the and of the body). Like this:

```
<script>
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    }
</script>
```

I was wondering if there are any security issues doing it like this? Should I stop doing it? I sadly couldn't find any information online regarding this topic. Also is it bad in general when I inject stuff into the window object or is it fine?

Was googling few hours but couldn't find any useful information.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you "using web3js with angular through the npm package is a bit cumbersome". I also use the cdn of web3@1.6.0. However since I'm using angular I dont create the instance of Web3 inside the script tag itself as what you have written above.

Comment: Im not yet sure about the security issue but I'm sure that creating an instance of Web3 in a script tag in Angular is a bit of anti pattern. Instead I write that inside of the ts file not in the index.html.

Comment: How can you use the web3 object inside of a ts file if you are "importing" it through a cdn? Usually you would import it through node_modules but without installing it through npm you can't do it like that. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I use this cdn of web3 and put this before closing tag of body
index.html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web3/1.6.0/web3.min.js"></script>

In my ts file usually I put this in a service class

declare let Web3: any;
declare let window: any;

export class MyWalletService {
async getBalance(address: string) {
    let web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(address);
    return web3.utils.fromWei(balance, 'ether');
  }
}

Make sure you declare the variable Web3 and window outside of service class. Makes sense?

Comment: sorry for bad formatting just copy and paste the code above in editor and format it to better view it.

Comment: This is exactly my template everytime I use web3 in angular since web3 of npm has a lot of issues to me.

Comment: Yep you are missing something :P

Comment: Ohhh I didn't know you could declare Web3 as "any" and then casually use it like normal. Thank you! You helped me a lot @iwantcheeseburger

Comment: Yep this is I usually do in 3rd party cdn's like web3 and paypal, etc. when I integrate it in angular.